# Conditionally join a list of strings in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a list like

```
users = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']
```

In a `Jinja` template I'd like to print a list of all users except `tom` joined. I cannot modify the variable before it's passed to the template.

I tried a list comprehension, and using Jinja's `reject` filter but I haven't been able to get these to work, e.g.

```
{{ [name for name in users if name != 'tom'] | join(', ') }}
```

gives a syntax error.

How can I join list items conditionally?

Answer (score 24):

Use [`reject`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#reject) filter with [`sameas`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#sameas) test:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> template = jinja2.Template("{{ users|reject('sameas', 'tom')|join(',') }}")
>>> template.render(users=['tom', 'dick', 'harry'])
u'dick,harry'
```

**UPDATE**

If you're using Jinja 2.8+, use [`equalto`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#equalto) instead of `sameas` as @Dougal commented; `sameas` tests with Python `is`, while `equalto` tests with `==`.

Comment: The [`equalto`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#equalto) test, introduced in Jinja 2.8, would now be better. `sameas` tests with Python `is`, while `equalto` tests with `==`; for strings, thanks to string interning, these will _often_ but not always agree.

Comment: @Dougal, Thank you for the information. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

This should work, as list comprehension is not directly supported. Ofcourse, appropiate filters will be better.

```
{% for name in users if name != 'tom'%}
    {{name}}
    {% if not loop.last %}
         {{','}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great alternative. Note that you can write "," instead of "{{','}}".

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with "equalto" test instead of "sameas"

Use [reject](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#reject) filter with [equalto](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#equalto) test:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> template = jinja2.Template("{{ items|reject('equalto', 'aa')|join(',') }}")
>>> template.render(users=['aa', 'bb', 'cc'])
u'bb,cc'
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to reject more than one value just try to write **`'in'` with list afterwards** instead of 'equalto'/'sameas':

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> template = jinja2.Template("{{ items|reject('in', ['a','b'])|join(',') }}")
>>> template.render(users=['a', 'b', 'c'])
u'c'
```